# Is there a way to merge rows?

Tags: r

I am using R..

I have a dataframe about reservations in a transportation company:

| Van | Route | Departure | Price | Customer ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U21 | LA - SF | 8:00:00 | 30.00 | 467866578 |
| U21 | LA - SF | 8:00:00 | 30.00 | 234656433 |
| U21 | LA - SF | 8:00:00 | 30.00 | 654343554 |
| U21 | LA - SF | 8:00:00 | 30.00 | 466534444 |
| U21 | LA - SF | 8:00:00 | 30.00 | 354543433 |
| U22 | LA - SD | 6:00:00 | 20.00 | 345464533 |
| U22 | LA - SD | 6:00:00 | 20.00 | 345456777 |
| U22 | LA - SD | 6:00:00 | 20.00 | 344565411 |
| U22 | LA - SD | 6:00:00 | 20.00 | 119873566 |

I would like to make a new data frame that shows this:

| Van | Route | Departure | Price | Tickets Sold | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U21 | LA - SF | 8:00:00 | 30.00 | 5 | 150.00 |
| U22 | LA - SD | 6:00:00 | 20.00 | 4 | 80.00 |

Thanks in advance!!!!! Please help :)

Answer (score 2):

or using `dplyr`

```r
library(dplyr)

df_new<-df %>%
  group_by(Van, Route, Departure, Price)  %>%
  summarize(`Tickets Sold`=n(),
            Revenue=sum(Price)) %>%
  ungroup()

df_new
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   Van   Route   Departure Price `Tickets Sold` Revenue
#>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>     <int>          <int>   <int>
#> 1 U21   LA - SF 8:00:00      30              5     150
#> 2 U22   LA - SD 6:00:00      20              4      80
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
# load package
library(data.table)

# set dataframe as datatable
setDT(df)

# calculate
df[, .(tickets_sold = .N
       , revenue = sum(Price)
       )
   , .(Van, Route, Departure, Price)
   ]
```

Comment: @MateoGuajardo My apologies, I had left out the group by columns. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can `dplyr::group_by()` the common variables and then use `dplyr::summarize()` to calculate the number of entries per group with `n()` and the total `Revenue` with `sum()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- structure(list(Van = c("U21", "U21", "U21", "U21", "U21", "U22", "U22", "U22", "U22"), Route = c("LA - SF", "LA - SF", "LA - SF", "LA - SF", "LA - SF", "LA - SD", "LA - SD", "LA - SD", "LA - SD"), Departure = c("8:00:00", "8:00:00", "8:00:00", "8:00:00", "8:00:00", "6:00:00", "6:00:00", "6:00:00", "6:00:00"), Price = c(30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 20, 20, 20, 20), Customer.ID = c(467866578L, 234656433L, 654343554L, 466534444L, 354543433L, 345464533L, 345456777L, 344565411L, 119873566L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

d %>% 
  group_by(across(Van:Departure)) %>% 
  summarize(Tickets_Sold = n(), Revenue = sum(Price), .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   Van   Route   Departure Tickets_Sold Revenue
#>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>            <int>   <dbl>
#> 1 U21   LA - SF 8:00:00              5     150
#> 2 U22   LA - SD 6:00:00              4      80
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>